# What is the difference between suus and eius?

Tags: word-comparison, pronouns, adjective, genitive

What is the difference between the possessive adjective

***suus*** (his, hers, its, theirs)
<sup>(and its declensions)</sup>

and the genitive, possessive pronoun

***eius*** (of her, of him, of it)?

Can these words be used interchangeably?

Comment: There was a suggested edit to replace "possessive pronoun" with "personal pronoun", but I rejected it to let you keep your original voice in the question. The word *eius* is not a standalone pronoun, but the genitive (and therefore possessive) form of the pronoun *is, ea, id*. Especially when it comes to pronouns, translations to English or any other language can be misleading.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta What I meant is that in the genitive case it acts like a possessive pronoun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunn's [*An Introduction to Ecclesiastical Latin*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4222):

> **62. Possessive Pronouns** are used adjectivally and are equivalent to the Gen. case of the personal or reflexive pronoun.
>
> In the first and second persons the Gen. of the personal pronoun is rarely found in the sense of a possessive pronoun. [Phil. 2:12](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=57&ch=2&l=12-#x).
>
> In the third person *suus* is used reflexively, that is when the person or thing to which it refers is the subject of the sentence or clause in which it stands.
>
> > Propterea ergo magis quaerebant eum Judaei interficere: quia non solum solvebat Sabbatum, sed et Patrem suum dicebat Deum.
> > *On this account therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he was not only breaking the Sabbath, but also because he said that God was his Father*.… Jn. 5:18
>
> When the person or thing referred to by the pronoun is not the subject of the sentence or clause in which it stands, the Gen. of a demonstrative pronoun (generally *ejus* or *eorum* etc.) is used as the possessive pronoun of the third person.
>
> > Princeps autem sacerdotum Ananias praecepit adstantibus sibi percutere os ejus.
> > *But the chief of the priests Ananias commanded those that stood by him to smite his mouth* (i.e. Paul’s mouth). Acts 23:2.
>
> Sometimes where no ambiguity is likely to be caused *suus* is used in a subordinate clause when the person or thing to which it refers is denoted by the subject of the main clause.
>
> > Idem cum Johanne ad nonam horam ad templum adibat, ubi paralyticum sanitati reformavit suae.
> > *He went with John to the temple at the ninth hour, where he restored the paralytic to his health*. Tert. *de Oratione* xxv.
>
> N.B. In Latin, as in French, the gender of a possessive pronoun does not depend on the gender of the word denoting the possessor; but possessive pronouns agree with the nouns which they qualify in gender, number and case, like adjectives.
>
> Sua mater, *His mother*. Suus pater, *Her father*.

Answer (score 13):

All forms of *se*, including *suus*, normally refer to the subject of the main clause of the sentence. *Eius*, however, normally does not refer to this subject, but to someone else. So the two words have different meanings.

> Sextus Tarquinius crudelis est. Lucretia praevidet mortem suam.

"S.T. is cruel. Lucretia foresees her own death."

> Sextus Tarquinius crudelis est. Lucretia praevidet mortem eius.

"S.T. is cruel. Lucretia foresees his death."

The words *suam* and *eius* must be interpreted this way in the examples above; *suam* cannot refer to Tarquinius, nor can *eius* refer to Lucretia.

Comment: Without the "_Sextus Tarquinius crudelis est._" context, could "_Lucretia prævidet mortem suam._" have the same meaning as "_Lucretia prævidet mortem eius._"?

Comment: @Geremia: I would say no: if it referred to Lucretia, the writer would have written *suam*. So not writing *suam* means the writer is denying that conexion.