# Grammar and Meaning in Context of EIUS

Tags: possessive-pronouns

I have a question regarding the translation of the Gregorian chant *OS JUSTI*, which Wikipedia claims to be used as gradual of the Commune Doctorum, and as introit I and gradual II of the Commune Confessoris non Pontificis. (I have the text from a choral piece of Anton Bruckner and did not check Bruckner's source.) The text reads:

> OS JUSTI MEDITABITUR SAPIENTIAM
>   ET LINGUA EIUS LOQUETUR JUDICIUM
>   LEX DEI EIUS IN CORDE IPSIUS
>   ET NON SUPPLANTABUNTUR GRESSUS EIUS

I wonder about the of grammar of *EIUS* in the different verses: If I see it correctly, this is Genitive Singular of *IS*. And I cannot bring this into accordance with the meaning of the verses I assume:

I read

> ET LINGUA **EIUS** LOQUETUR JUDICIUM

as something like *And **his** tongue speaks right*, so EIUS means *his*. But how is this? Why is not the more direct (?) *SUUS* being used here?

The analogue problems occurs at

> LEX DEI EIUS IN CORDE IPSIUS

Here I am not sure if this must be read as *The law of his god is in his heart* or simply as *The law of god is in his heart*, and of course also at

> ET NON SUPPLANTABUNTUR GRESSUS EIUS

which I read as *And his pace will not be made stumble*.

The accepted answer of [What is the difference between suus and eius?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/what-is-the-difference-between-suus-and-eius) states, that *EIUS*, in contrary to *SUUS* is usually not referring to the subject of the main clause. But I don't think that this rule does apply here, becaus *JUSTUS* is the only person present in the whole text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule does apply -- it's a syntactic rule, not a semantic one. Since the subjects are *lingua* etc. rather than *justus*, the possessives are not reflexive, so *eius* is used rather than *suus*.

For *lex dei eius*, this does mean *the law of his god* -- there's nothing else *eius* could be doing here. Looking at the Hebrew source confirms this -- the text is taken from [Psalm 37:30-31](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2637.htm), which does indeed say תּוֹרַת אֱלֹהָיו בְּלִבּוֹ *The law of his god is in his heart*.